# Как узнать group_id в базе данных, зная только имя пользователя? (RedBeanPHP)

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Создаю АдминПанель на сайте, сейчас занят вопросом ограничения доступа к этой панели обычным пользователям.

У каждого пользователя есть свой *group_id* (1-user / 2-owner / 3-admin). При авторизации у каждого пользователя создается сессия, в которой хранится имя. При переходе на страницу админки я хочу сделать проверку на ранг пользователя (group_id), если его ранг ниже 2 - перенаправляем на главную страницу.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: использую `RedBeanPHP`, необходимо зная только имя пользователя (другая информация неизвестна) определять его *group_id*. В документации RedBean я нашел несколько функций:

1. `$book  = R::findOne( 'book', ' title = ? ', [ 'SQL Dreams' ] );` - поиск 
   одного
2. `$book = R::load('book', $id);` - загрузка данных из БД

В аргументах обоих функций указывается только название таблицы и id. Возможно ли мне вытащить из БД group_id, зная только имя пользователя из сессии?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то так:

```
   $book = R::findOne('book', 'name = ?', [$_SESSION['name']])

    if ($book['group_id'] == '2') { header('Location: /'); }
```